# Java multipart RSA decryption

Tags: java, rsa, phpseclib

I am encrypting data with phpseclib on a server

```
$rsa->loadKey($encryptkey);
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($str);
```

and receiving it in my Java application. The data is 384 bytes (3*128).

In Java I am trying to decrypt that (they keys have been distributed properly) but I am getting this exception:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 128 bytes
```

Below is the code I am working with. I have 2 line with `data =` because I am confused as to whether this situation counts as a multistage decryption, hence the use update. If it does, I don't understand how to use update and doFinal to get the decrypted data (my google skills didn't cut it here).

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pr);
data = cipher.update(encrypted_data);
data = cipher.doFinal();
System.out.println(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1` the phpseclib breaks up the plaintext into chunks of the appropriate size and RSA-encrypts each chunk separately (see the code starting at line # 2548 [here](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/700d28f64296ae74542d5614e598dca6ecf9cc67/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php#L2548)). Java refuses to do this -- which is the correct behavior in my opinion -- and just throws an exception.

You must emulate the behavior of phpseclib yourself in your Java code. You do this by first computing the length in bytes of your RSA modulus, by for example the following:

```
int lenBytes = (((RSAKey)pr).getModulus().bitLength() + 7 ) / 8;
```

and then break your encrypted data into `lenBytes` chunks. Decrypt each chunk separately. The result of each decryption will be at plaintext of at most `lenBytes - 11` bytes long. Concatenate all the plaintexts together, perhaps using something like a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `update` line, and change the `doFinal` call to `doFinal(encrypted_data)` - just decrypt this as a single-part operation

The only reason to do multi-part encryption/decryption is if the data isn't contiguous in memory (e.g. if your encrypted data was in 3 different 128-bit `byte[]`s, or if you were working with an IOstream) - otherwise, always do single-part encryption/decryption by putting the entire `byte[]` in the `doFinal` call.  (I suppose it might also be possible to encrypt/decrypt in parallel by using multi-part encryption/decryption, but I've never been enough of a glutton for punishment to try to implement this.)

Comment: Thanks for your time. The method you mention was how I originally tried doing this but I got the same exception as I described in the question. Do you know what that might be?

Comment: What size key are you using?  RSA can only encrypt/decrypt a number of bytes equal to your key size / 8, -11 if you're using padding.  If you use a 4096-bit key then that should do the trick.  Alternatively, encrypt your data with AES, and use RSA to encrypt the AES key.

Comment: If you take away the padding then you ought to be able to make do with a 3072-bit key - if your data is an exact multiple of 128 then you shouldn't need padding